# Visual Studio Code Running Environment

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm mostly using VSCode. I have two questions:

1. In the case of having a compiler error, VSCode warns you while you are writing the code (before you compile/run your program.) How I can do this?
2. How I can have the environment so that when I click on run button it compiles, runs and shows me the output in the terminal section?

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe this extension could be of help: [C/C++ Advanced Lint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jbenden.c-cpp-flylint)
2. Install [Microsoft's C/C++ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) and have a look at [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc). Especially the topic "Create a build task" should be of interest for you (after you've done all the prerequisites steps.

Comment: In addition to these, I have found an extension called "Code runner" .This was what have tried to find.